# Are questions by new users rising, lately?

Tags: discussion, new-users, statistics

Is it me, or there are many more "first time user" questions lately? 
If yes, would this mean there's a growing Blender interest by "newcomers"? But who they are really? 3D newbies, Blender newbies or BSE newbies?

This made me think: are there public statistics about such (and maybe other) trends/usage here on BSE? I wonder also if during user registration a few questions could be added to know what related tech user already knows about, and how much (maybe how many years), about  Blender or other 2D or 3D packages, just to get an idea but also to know better how to answer, without asking each time...

Also, it could be interesting to know trends/usage related to posting, answering, accepting, and all other BSE workflow actions and states...

Maybe I'm just curious today, but I wonder if knowing better users, could help to answer question better, in the end...

Comment: Here's a nice [compilation of statistics](http://sese.evbpc.com/Sites/Detail?SiteId=64993809-6eff-e511-80c0-00155d918203). If you are proficient with SQL queries, then you might be interested in the [stackexchange data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/)